# How to Get only json key-value that do not have child json with underscore?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have the json as follow

```js
{
     "first_name":"dinesh",
     "last_name":"dabhi",
     "email":"dinesh@complitech.net",
     "street_no":"36",
     "role":{
       "admin":{
              "refferal_source":null,
              "customer_service":null,
              "can_associate_patient":false,
        },
       "patient":{
             "refferenical_source":"abc",
             "reward_point":null, 
        }
    }
}
```

I want to only get the profile data [firstname, last_name , etc] not the perticular data related to role of the user. How can i do this with underscore?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick):

```js
var object = {
    "first_name":"dinesh",
    "last_name":"dabhi",
    "email":"dinesh@complitech.net",
    "street_no":"36",
    "role":{
        "admin":{ "refferal_source":null, "customer_service":null, "can_associate_patient":false },
        "patient":{ "refferenical_source":"abc", "reward_point":null }
    }
}

var result = _.pick(object, "first_name", "last_name", "email");

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the omit method from the underscore.

> _.omit({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'userid');
>   => {name: 'moe', age: 50}

Using that I can omit the role object.